# Trim the URL and fetch the name after the last Slash in c#

Tags: c#, string, trim

I need to **Trim** the URL that I am fetching from the Database and need to show the value after the **last Slash(/)**.

Tried using Trim Function.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(Int64 NurseId, Int64 PostedJobId, Int64 DocumentId)
    {
        NurseDAL objNurseDAL = new NurseDAL();

        Result objResult = objNurseDAL.FetchDocumentURLfromDocID(DocumentId);


        string path = "D:/TFSProjects/Dot Net Project/NurseOneStop.WebSite/NurseOneStop.WebSite/";
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + objResult.Results.DocumentUrl);
        var URL = objResult.Results.DocumentUrl; //(/Content/Images/UploadedDocuments/20190205131053233.pdf)

        string fileName = filename.extension;
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

The expected output should be 20190205131053233.pdf from the string URL: /Content/Images/UploadedDocuments/20190205131053233.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim can be used only to trim specific characters from a specified string. For this scenario, you can use `Path.GetFileName(fileName)`. You will have to refer `System.IO` by adding a using statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use split to create an array

```
string filename = objResult.Results.DocumentUrl.Split('/').Last;
```

However you may only use that if the delimiter is /. If it's a path, you may encounter \ (Windows) or / (POSIX), at which point it might be a good idea to use System.IO.Path.GetFileName.